# While loop inside of while loop with MySql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, do-while

I need to know how can I make this query, because right now only show me the first value in each day, but not the entire values per day.

I need that the query in the second while show me all the users in that day and so on in each day

Here my queries:

```
//First While:
<?php
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(id) AS total, fTera, DATE_FORMAT(fTera, '%d') AS day, DATE_FORMAT(fTera, '%d %M %Y') AS date
FROM TERA WHERE MONTH(fTera) = MONTH(current_date) AND YEAR(fTera) = YEAR(current_date) AND active != 0
GROUP BY date ASC");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $fT = $row['fTera'];
    $paci = $row['total'];
        
?>
//Second While
    <?php
    $tera = $conn->prepare("SELECT *
    FROM TERA WHERE fTera = :fecha AND active != 0");
    $tera->bindParam(':fecha', $fT, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $tera->execute();
    $tPaci = 0;
    while($row1 = $tera->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if($paci != $tPaci):
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $row1['nombre']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        endif;
        $tPaci++; 
        } 
    ?>
//End Second While

<?php } ?>

//End First While
```

Comment: your first query is wrong, and should not run, see if you can make a https://dbfiddle.uk and run your first query and see what happens

Answer (score -1):

I already did it

I change this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE fTera = :fecha
```

To this one:

```
fTera >= '$fT' AND fTera < '$fT' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

The Second query right now is:

```
$tera = $conn->prepare("SELECT *
FROM TERA WHERE fTera >= '$fT' AND fTera < '$fT' + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND active != 0");
$tera->execute();
....
```

Comment: this would be vulnerable to sql injection, besides his first query is the problem